# Multiple UIPickerview in single UIViewController can't add soap response

Tags: objective-c, iphone, soap

```
In my Application I have 3 UIPickerView and data is added using soap web service,response is getting ok but can't add in picker view,i'm new for objectives programming,please suggest me. 

here I post some code.

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    picker1 = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:picker1];
    _customPickerArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self dropdown];
}
-(void)dropdown
{
    NSLog(@"dropdown method is call");

    NSString *envalope=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                        "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                        "<soap:Body>\n"
                        "<Value xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                        “</Value>\n"
                        "</soap:Body>\n"
                        "</soap:Envelope>"];

    envalope=[NSString stringWithFormat:envalope];
    NSData *envelope = [envalope dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *url = @“ABC.asmx";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request1 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];    
}
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser didStartElement:(NSString *) elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *) qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if( [elementName isEqualToString:@“ValueResult"])
    {
        if (!soapResults)
        {
            soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        }
        elementFound = YES;
    }


}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (elementFound)
    {
        [soapResults appendString: string];
        NSArray * jsonarr =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[string  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"print array :%@",jsonarr);
        for (NSDictionary * d in jsonarr)
        {
            if ([d objectForKey:@"CLR"]!=[NSNull null])
            {
                self.colorstring=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[d objectForKey:@"CLR"]];
                 NSLog(@"pVALUE FOR CLR :%@",self.colorstring);
                [_customPickerArray1 addObject:self.colorstring];
                NSLog(@"pVALUE AFTER ARRAY FILL:%d",_customPickerArray1.count);

            }
            else
            {
                self.colorstring=@"";
            }
        }
    } 
}
- (int)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 3;
}

// The number of rows of data
- (int)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    if([pickerView tag]==1)
    {

        return _customPickerArray1.count;
    }
    else if([pickerView tag]==2)
    {
        return _customPickerArray1.count;
    }else if([pickerView tag]==3){
       return _customPickerArray1.count;
    }
}
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if([pickerView tag]==1)
    {

       return _customPickerArray1[row];
    }
    else if([pickerView tag]==2)
    {
        return _customPickerArray1[row];
    }else if([pickerView tag]==3){
       return _customPickerArray1[row];
    }
   }
@end
```

first I'm declare 3 picker view in xib and set datasource and delegate, and in background soap web service is call for add data in pickerview ,but soap response is getting back successfully but soap response is also set in NSMutablearray but not  represent in picker view.

Comment: try to reload pickerview than check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get response and parse it through `parser` write respective `picker` reload method so you will get all `datasource` methods call and data will fill in your respective `picker`.

```
[picker reloadAllComponents];
```

Hope this will help.